# KEY can't be remove or nulled why so?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code to initialize the key**

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  KEY = prefs.getString('KEY');
```

**Code to remove the key**

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              await prefs.remove('KEY');
```

Comment: I believe that code should work fine. What error do you get?

Comment: This isn't working so i'm assuming it's not null or empty. '/login': (context) =>
            (KEY == null || KEY!.isEmpty) ? const Login() : Profile(),

Comment: Can you share the error logs?

Comment: On Clicking Logout, I'm removing key and redirecting using NamedRoute to '/login' which checks the following condition and redirects accordingly.

Comment: removing it from the preference doesn't automatically clear the variable. You would need to call `KEY = null;` after the removal from shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

**need to call**

```
KEY = null;
```

after the removal from shared preferences –
Ivo Beckers